# How to get object values from jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a list of names to search through that also contain an id value I want to use to lookup the further infomation when selected and populate a form with. The generated list looks like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var allplayers = [
    { label: "Name of one", id:"1393" }, 
            { label: "Name of two", id:"325" }, 
            { label: "Name of one", id:"637" }
            ];
    }

    $( "#searchplayers" ).autocomplete({
        source: allplayers
    });

$( "#searchplayers" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
          alert(ui.item.id);  //this is how to get item id
});
</script>
```

Right now it just adds the value into the text input, how can I grab the id associated with it when the select function is called. How can I get the id of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ui object has an item

```
$( "#searchplayers" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item);
});
```

Comment: D'oh, it was that simple. I learnt something new nonetheless, thank you.